# Zend fetchRow() not working

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I'm trying to fetch a row with a where statement but for some reason it throws an error at me.

This is the line
`$row = $this->getDbTable()->fetchRow("order = $order");`

I've put a die(); before this line and it does die,
Then I've put a die(); after this line and the die() doesn't get executed but throws an error.

The error doesn't help me much it only says "An error occurred Application error", there's nothing in my php error log either.

Help!

Comment: Whats happens if you do something simpler like `->fetchAll();`?

Comment: the fetchAll(); works fine. I've managed to work around the fetchRow() but for future project I really need to know what's wrong with fetchRow here.

Comment: it's an Integer, I use this $order to sort my rows (0, 1, 2, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your comments, I would try doing the `where` part 'properly'? E.g.:

```
$select = $this->getDbTable()->select()->where('order = ?', $order);
$row = $this->getDbTable()->fetchRow($select);
```

What is the situation you are needing to select by `order`? Is there a primary key you can select by?

**Update:**

Given your comments, maybe use `update` directly:

```
$table = $this->getDbTable();

$data = array( 'order' => $order+1 );

$where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('order = ?', $order);

$table->update($data, $where);
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error, die() before the line gets executed when placed after the line it doesn't. I needed to select on order because I wanted to be able to edit the order. When I want to move from order 3 to 4. I needed to find the 2 rows containing these orders then switching them and saving them again. I've fixed it using fetchAll(null, 'order') then $i = 0; foreach($objects as $object) if($object->getOrder() == $order) $object->setOrder($order); $objects[++$i]->setOrder(++$order); endif; $i++; endforeach;

Comment: Ah right, doing a fetchAll just to change two rows doesn't sound too efficient.  Maybe use update directly? see updated answer.

Comment: That would be fine but the problem is that I need to switch the two, so if I update a row with order 2 to 3. Then how can I change the row with order 3 to 2, as I have 2 rows now with order = 3 :-)

Comment: This is why I asked about having a primary key to select by instead.  How are you starting the whole '2 needs to be swapped with 3' process?  Surely you should have the primary key available?  That way you could just move 3 to 2, selecting by order, then you have two set to 2, but you move the one you wanted to move to 3 by selecting by primary key.  Hopefully that makes sense :)

Comment: Oh I see now, yes you're right. I use a primary key called id wich I also pass through as a param to my Action. So with that id I can store ($currentOrder) and change the order of the current object ($currentOrder + 1) and with the var $currentOrder search and update the other object's order.